# geopandas .explore - How to set marker icon?

Tags: python, geopandas, marker, folium

I want to change the icon of the marker in .explore to a house icon.

I have read the documentation of [geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) and [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html), still not able to understand it.

```
geo_df.explore(m=m
                    ,column='pop'
                    ,tooltip={"name","pop"}     
                    ,cmap='summer'
                    ,style_kwds=dict(stroke=True,weight=1,color='black', opacity=0.5, fillOpacity=0.9)
                    ,marker_kwds=dict(radius=5,icon=folium.Icon(icon='house-blank'))              
                    ,name="Residental"
                    )
```

The icon represents the position of the house and I set colormap base on an integer value.

[image]

Also, is there a way to make a radius size don't change when zoom?

Comment: Isn't the icon for the house 'home'? I don't know if they are all available, but see [this](https://glyphsearch.com/?library=glyphicons) for a list of icons. `icon=folium.Icon(icon='home')`

Comment: I am not sure whether you still can use the `cmap` when using custom markers, but in order to use `folium` markers, you will have to tell geopandas to do so, by setting the `marker_type='marker'`:

`geo_df.explore(m=m

                    ,column='pop'
                    ,marker_type='marker' 
                    ,marker_kwds=dict(radius=5,icon=folium.Icon(icon='house-blank'))              
                    )`

Comment: And it seems like only `folium.map.Icon`s are accepted:
`geo_df.explore(m=m, marker_type='marker', marker_kwds={'icon': folium.map.Icon(icon='home', prefix='fa')})`

Comment: Thank you, Christian Weber: for your method, the icon are working but cmap does not, and as the distance between each point is close to each other, it hard to look at and too crowded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature in **folium** [GeoJson Marker](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/957) and a feature in **geopandas** [flexible style function](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2377) that can be used to meet your requirement

1. make your code a MWE using cities dataset
2. define `marker_type` and `marker_kwds` so that a **DivIcon** is used
3. define a **style function** so that marker is formatted as you require.  Actually using column created by **geopandas** from `column` and `cmap` parameters
4. the size of markers does not change on zoom as *font-size* has been set in pixels

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import numpy as np

geo_df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
geo_df["pop"] = np.random.randint(1, 5, len(geo_df))
m = None

m = geo_df.explore(
    m=m,
    column="pop",
    tooltip={"name", "pop"},
    cmap="summer",
    style_kwds=dict(
        style_function=lambda x: {
            "html": f"""<span   class="fa fa-home" 
                                style="color:{x["properties"]["__folium_color"]};
                                font-size:14px"></span>"""
        },
    ),
    marker_type="marker",
    marker_kwds=dict(icon=folium.DivIcon()),
    name="Residental",
    height=300,
    width=300,
)

m
```

#### output

[image]

#### responsive and icon borders

using this as inspiration [Injecting CSS and JavaScript into folium](https://nagasudhir.blogspot.com/2021/08/draw-text-on-python-folium-maps-using.html)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import numpy as np

geo_df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
geo_df["pop"] = np.random.randint(1, 5, len(geo_df))
m = None

m = geo_df.explore(
    m=m,
    column="pop",
    tooltip={"name", "pop"},
    cmap="summer",
    style_kwds=dict(
        style_function=lambda x: {
            "html": f"""<span   class="fa fa-home" 
                                style="color:{x["properties"]["__folium_color"]};">
                        </span>"""
        },
    ),
    marker_type="marker",
    marker_kwds=dict(icon=folium.DivIcon(class_name="mapIcon")),
    name="Residental",
    height=300,
    width=500,
)

# inject html into the map html
m.get_root().html.add_child(
    folium.Element(
        """
<style>
.mapIcon {
    font-size:large;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var sizeFromZoom = function(z){return z<3 ? "small" : (0.5*z)+"em"}
    var updateIconSizes = function(){
        var mapZoom = {mapObj}.getZoom();
        var txtSize = sizeFromZoom(mapZoom);
        $(".mapIcon").css("font-size", txtSize);
    }
    updateIconSizes();
    {mapObj}.on("zoomend", updateIconSizes);
}
</script>
""".replace(
            "{mapObj}", m.get_name()
        )
    )
)

m
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rob Raymond: your answer is exactly what I am looking for, but I got the error in line  `style_function`. I am currently finding a way to fix it
`TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable`

Comment: do you get the error when using sample geometry or your geometry? are you using **geopandas** 0.11+?

Comment: Both, my version is 0.10.0. I will update it to 0.11 and try again

Comment: It worked now, **thanks!** but I try to add stroke to the icon and set the size to **change** when zoom, but it does not work is there a way?

Comment: have updated for responsive,  needs additional techniques to inject CSS and Javascript

Comment: I found a way to add stroke but i'm sure it is not a correct way, by add  `text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000` to `style` in `style_function` and stack multiple shadows to make look like stroke.

Comment: have effectively used same technique in responsive solution as well